# A-frame Teleportation Mechanic? (Desktop/Cardboard)

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I'm working on a project for aframe in which at some point the user "enters" a room (really just getting teleported to a different point in the environment) on clicking on a button.
I have tried using Don McCurdy's checkpoint system as well as simple javascript, but I don't have much knowledge of js and would appreciate any help you could provide.

Example of what I have tried:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('teleporter', {

init: function () {
  var button = document.querySelector('#button');
  var cam = document.querySelector('#camera');

  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    cam.setAttribute('position', '10, 1.6, 10');
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

1. You teleport to the button:
   create a component, which will be attached to the button, and will teleport the camera to the button:

   ```
   init: function () {
     var cam = document.querySelector('a-camera');
     var position = this.el.getAttribute("position");
     this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
       cam.setAttribute('position', position);
     });
   }
   ```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/115edevs/6/).

2. You specify where to teleport by defining a schema:
   add a schema to the component:

   ```
   AFRAME.registerComponent('teleporter', {
    schema: {
      position: {default: "0 0 0"},
    },
    init: function () {
      var cam = document.querySelector('a-camera');
      var position = this.data.position;
      this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        cam.setAttribute('position', position);
      });
    }
   });
   ```

and use it like this:

```
<a-sphere position="5 1.25 -6" radius="1.25" color="#EFFD5E"
   teleporter="position:5 1.6 -6"></a-sphere>
```

defining where You want the player to teleport after the click.

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/115edevs/5/).

Comment: @CormacDonnelly glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be very similar to your initial idea (where position should be without commas):

```
  <a-box
    position="0 2 2"
    color="red"
    class="clickable" onClick="document.querySelector('#cam').setAttribute('position','0 2 2')";
    >
  </a-box>

  <a-box
    position="10 2 2"
    color="blue"
    class="clickable" onClick="document.querySelector('#cam').setAttribute('position','10 2 2')";
    >
  </a-box>
```

Working example here:
http://curious-electric.com/aframe/teleport/